# Windows Phone 7 Dynamic ListBox Template

Tags: xml, windows-phone-7

I've just recently started working on an app that displays a bunch of xml data in a listBox, but the problem is not every xml item has a child value (In my problem, upload), so its listBox code shouldn't be displayed.

Example:

```
<item>
     <id>1</id>
     <body>Some text</body>
     <upload></upload>
     <created>Some text</created>
</item>
```

I'm getting the data and populating my list this way:

```
var data = from query in loadedData.Descendants("item")
                   select new droppedItem
                   {
                       Id = (int)query.Element("id"),
                       Body = (string)query.Element("body"),
                       Upload = (string)query.Element("upload"),
                       Created = (DateTime)ConvertFromUnixTimestamp((double)query.Element("created"))
                   };
        userDrops.ItemsSource = data;
```

And my xaml looks like:

```
<ListBox Margin="0,0,-12,0" Name="userDrops">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17" Width="432">
                            <RichTextBox>
                                <Paragraph>
                                    <Run Text="{Binding Body}" FontSize="25" FontFamily="Segoe WP"></Run>
                                </Paragraph>
                                <Paragraph>
                                    <Hyperlink NavigateUri="{Binding Upload}" TargetName="_blank" FontSize="25" FontFamily="Segoe WP">{Binding Upload}</Hyperlink>
                                </Paragraph>
                                <Paragraph>
                                    <Run Text="{Binding Created}" FontFamily="Segoe WP SemiLight"></Run>
                                </Paragraph>
                            </RichTextBox>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

What I want to do is only display the paragraph holding the upload info if the xml upload child holds a value. Otherwise, just remove it from the listBox. I can't figure out how to change the basic listBox template though.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Do you mean if Upload is empty, you want to hide the whole `StackPanel`?

Comment: No, I mean if Upload is empty, I want to hide `<Paragraph><Hyperlink/></Paragraph>` (The paragraph holding the Upload value)

Comment: If Upload is empty, it won't display anything, correct?

Comment: Correct, but the paragraph is still taking up height, so between the Body paragraph and Created paragraph, there is a gap (the empty Upload paragraph)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using `TextBlocks` to display Body and Created? The middle part would be a `RichTextBox`, you can use a Visibility converter to toggle hide/show if Upload is empty.

You need to include your converter in your xaml page first,

```
xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:xxx.Converters;assembly=xxx"

<converters:VisibilityConverter x:Key="visibilityConverter" />
```

then use it inside your template,

```
                <StackPanel Margin="40,237,8,326" Width="432" Grid.Row="1"> 
                    <RichTextBox> 
                        <Paragraph> 
                            <Run Text="{Binding Body}" FontSize="25" FontFamily="Segoe WP"></Run> 
                        </Paragraph>
                    </RichTextBox> 
                    <RichTextBox Visibility="{Binding Upload, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}">
                        <Paragraph> 
                            <Hyperlink NavigateUri="{Binding Upload}" TargetName="_blank" FontSize="25" FontFamily="Segoe WP">{Binding Upload}</Hyperlink> 
                        </Paragraph>
                    </RichTextBox> 
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Created}" FontFamily="Segoe WP SemiLight"/>
                </StackPanel>
```

The converter should be something like this,

```
  public class VisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            bool visible = true;

            if (value is bool)
            {
                visible = (bool)value;
            }
            else if (value is int || value is short || value is long)
            {
                visible = 0 != (int)value;
            }
            else if (value is float || value is double)
            {
                visible = 0.0 != (double)value;
            }
            else if (value is string) {
                visible = ((string)value).Length > 0;
            }
            else if (value == null) {
                visible = false;
            }

            if ((string)parameter == "!")
            {
                visible = !visible;
            }

            return visible ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

For more info regarding value converter, see [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/psheriff/archive/2010/09/24/using-value-converters-in-silverlight.aspx).

**UPDATE**

In your App.xaml, do this,

```
<Application xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
             xmlns:sg="http://schemas.stargategroup.com.au/2010/xaml/presentation" 
             xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:xxx.Converters"
             x:Class="xxx.Application.App">

    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <converters:VisibilityConverter x:Key="VisibilityConverter" />
```

Comment: The problem I run into with using `TextBlocks` to display Body is that Body will have `Hyperlink` in it. How would I use a Visibility converter though? (I hadn't ever looked at silverlight until 2 days ago, so this is all new to me)

Comment: Just tested what the layout would look like if I just made 3 separate `RickTextBoxs` and it looks fine, so if there is a way to hide a `RichTextBox` on the fly based on the Binding, that seems like it would work.

Comment: See my updated answer. What you can do is, create two `RichTextBoxes`, one for displaying the Body, one for displaying the Upload. In the upload `RichTextBox`, you use a visibility converter to check if Upload is empty, if it is, set visibility to null. I will upload a visibility converter sample shortly.

Comment: I had no idea that sort of thing was possible, thanks. Though I'm getting a `"StringToVisibilityConverter" could not be resolved.` error and my app is closing. EDIT: Oh, it's a separate class. Nevermind in that case. I'll look into it now

Comment: Yes you need to add in the converter class, include it and then use it like that. :)

Comment: I assume I add this into the MainPage.xaml.cs file?

Comment: No, you need to add it into the xaml page. Actually you can put it inside your App.xaml so it will be shared across all your pages.

Comment: Now I'm sorta lost. You mean for example in the App.xaml file after `<Application></Application>`? Just paste that class directly after it?

Comment: I've been messing around with all of it but I'm still confused where the `public class VisibilityConverter : IValueConverter` goes.

Comment: If you could just google how a value converter works in silverlight/wp7 you would know... Just take a look at the link I put in the post...

Comment: I got it! Thanks so much. Though I actually ended up putting it in my MainPage class (randomly as I was using trial and error to get this to work). I'll end up moving it to its own separate class. Thanks again for all the help. Sorry I knew so little about Silverlight to begin with :/